# How do I change this object in OracleForms?

Tags: oracleforms

Using OracleForms Builder 32bit v 11.2. 
How do I change the name of the form as highlighted in this picture?[image: OracleForm]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is controlled by the "Title" property of the window. You can set it via the Forms Designer property palette, having selected the window in question. Or you can change it programatically using the Forms built-in `set_window_property`, e.g.:

`set_window_property('my_window_name', TITLE, 'New Title');`